# SQL Server: re-run same lines

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The R language has this nice feature where you can re-run the same lines of code with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Does anyone know if that's possible with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

I find myself modify a bit of code and wanting to run it again, quickly. The highlight and execute is getting a bit repetitive. I would like a shortcut to run the same lines without the need to highlight.

Comment: Nothing I know of will do this in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in SSMS. Both of these will run the **highlighted** SQL.

Hovering over the Execute button will have also displayed a tooltip to tell you this.

[image]